# ASP.Net pages call to Reporting Service Web Service get "401 Unauthorized" error

Tags: asp.net, iis, reporting-services, impersonation, credentials

I wrote an ASP.Net which acts as our company's hub of reporting services. I reference to the MSDN, having the following settings:

```
    rs = New ReportingService()
    rs.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    rs.PreAuthenticate = True
    rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
```

and testing under the Visual Studio 2008, it works fine. However once I publish it to the IIS (5.5) on my development PC (Windows XP) for pre-production deployment testing, and access it from another workstation, it results at "HTTP 401: Unauthorized error". (But it works by local access)

I have the following lines in the Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

And I've the following settings in the IIS Server:

1. NO Anonymous Access (under Directory Security)
2. Use Integrated Windows Authentication (under Directory Security)

Please kindly advise!

Many thanks.
William

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably never hear of delegation, right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx

Make delegation work, and then you can pass the credential to reporting services.

Comment: Hi Lex, I heard that, but I'm not familiar with it. I referenced to the MSDN, and tried the necessary coding & settings, but it doesn't work. I think I found the explanation from: http://odetocode.com/articles/216.aspx

Comment: it should be so-called "one-hop limit with NTLM authentication". In order to delegate the credentials over the one-hop limit, the company's system team need to be involved, i.e. I've no right to do that. Please advise if anything wrong.

Comment: That article I pasted contains the hint. If your company does not allow double hop, then switching to "basic authentication + SSL" or "protocol transition" are the only remaining options.